# Does it make sense to have error bars if there is no uncertainty in calculating the percentage?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample, population

I know a couple questions have been asked on this site that are similar, but they were slightly different from mine, and the answers don't seem to apply to me directly. I have the following simple table that has the percentage for each category in my sample. And I have made the corresponding bar chart. I haven't put any error bars on the bars because I cannot understand what would they represent. In this population, I have absolutely no uncertainty in saying, for example, that C1 is present in 25.56% of the cases. There are no replicates. So this number is basically like frequency.

From my reading of the other answers, it appears that all such estimates must be accompanied by an error. Could someone help me understand why, and also how I would go about calculating the error? I know Excel can easily give you different kinds of errors, but for this really simple data, how would you calculate it?

[image]

Comment: You say: "I have absolutely no uncertainty", i.e. you are sure that there is no error in you numbers. If you are sure there are no errors, you don't need (have) error bars. But note, however, that your percentages **don't** add up to 100%.

Comment: @frank thank you for your kind comment. Regarding the percentages not adding up to 100, that is alright - there is overlap between the categories. Regarding your first point, I should clarify that I don't claim to have any more certainty that there is no error, than anyone else who gets this data and calculates these %s would have. Like if there was a classroom of 10 students and 3 wore white, I assume to have no uncertainty in saying that the % of white clothed students is 30%. Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: It would help if you would tell us: what is your data, how do you obtain those percentages, what error should be displayed with the error bars, and, most importantly: what is your actual goal?

Comment: @frank the data is looking at the presence of particular immune systems (C1,C2,C3) in a set of 399 bacterial genomes. A tool was used to find if any of the systems existed in each genome. Once I had the frequencies of each system type, I just divided that number by the total # of genomes to get the %s. My goal is to display the % prevalence of each system type in this population. And regarding what error should be displayed, I am not sure. I think this is the entire sample, and there are no replicates, these %s might just be point estimates like in the classroom example. But I could be wrong

Comment: So the tool can also detect multiple immune systems (IS) in the same genome? Anyway: if you don't know the IS of any of the genomes and then you apply your tool to get an assignment of IS to genome, then the error is the error of the tool. Does the documentation of the tool come with some statement w.r.t. its error?